# geth 1.10.15 where is syncmode --fast

Tags: synchronization, fast-sync

Setting up geth 1.10.15.  There are only 3 syncmodes:  snap, full and light. There is no fast anymore

What is snap?  Is it the same as fast.

To get it to run fast I use full or snap

Thank-you in advance.
Primedev

Comment: snap replaced fast.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no fast anymore.
The snap is used as default to download the initial state and after that `geth` switches to `full` mode.